# Can we add error and event handlers before jwplayer player can generate those errors?

Tags: jwplayer

The JWPlayer JS API seems unclear about what happens during .setup(). The docs recommend waiting until .setup() is completed and the player is ready. Presumably they mean the ready() event is triggered. What is the proper way to register handlers for setupError, ready and other error events before calling .setup() ?
Does anyone know what JWPlayer does with the file(s) before .setup() completes?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to chain all of your event handlers to the same setup() call:

```
var playerInstance = jwplayer('myVideo');
playerInstance.setup({
    file: 'bunny.mp4',
}).on('ready',function(){
    console.log('ready');      
}).on('setupError',function(){
    console.log('setupError')
});
```

What are you trying to do to the file before setup() completes?

As far as what JW Player does with the file, we do not request the file URL until the player starts playback unless you are using one of the preload options as documented at https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/docs/developer-guide/customization/configuration-reference/

Comment: We are getting setup errors when trying to play 360 videos. So, we need to register a 360 handler before the .setup() call, not after, correct?